# What is the differences between InstallUtils versions

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, wmi, installutil

Assuming I want to install a service using InstallUtil.
What will be the differences in the service and how it will affect my program if I run installUtils from

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

or from

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

What will happen if I installed my service using v2.n.n InstallUtil version, and then uninstalles .net 3.5 (so I will have only v4.0)

Comment: Are you asking difference between .NET framework 2.0 and 4.0 ?

Comment: One targets framework 2.0 and the other 4.0, your answer lies in the difference between them

Comment: I understand that. but I am asking hiw it would affect my program. Would the dlls be regisered in a different location, etc.

Comment: @user844541 Your program *not* installed to the framework directories and the GAC is shared across .NET versions. Now, if your program *requires* .NET 2/3.5 (it will require this or not  *independently* from installutil) and .NET 2/3.5 is uninstalled (can it be these days?) then it will fail to run as a dependency is no longer fulfilled.

Comment: @Paul so you are saying that if I used one version of installUtil it doesn't have any effect on my application?